# Development and Testing Web Client Application

Tags: apache, deployment, web, client-side

This is a noob question.

I am developing a web (client-side) application. I have a *development* directory, which contains the web stuff: HTML, CSS, and JS files.

Now I would like to test it. I am running `apache` which uses `/var/www` as the default web directory. I can copy my *development* directory as a whole to `/var/www` and test the application in the browser.

Another option is to configure `apache` to map `/my-app` directly to my *development* directory `~/dev/my-app`.

Which option would you prefer ?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to add a soft link in your /var/www directory towards your dev (or build) directory. So you don't have to change apache settings and you let the code you're making in your home directory.

(of course, this is for a development computer, not visible from internet)